# Не работают примеры из пакета Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Программирую на Python 2.7. Установил пакет Kivy в свой Linux. Запуск примеров (любых) Kivy выводит лишь черное окошко на экран. В чем может быть причина?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class TestApp(App):

    def animate(self, instance):
        # create an animation object. 
        animation = Animation(pos=(100, 100), t='out_bounce')
        animation += Animation(pos=(200, 100), t='out_bounce')
        animation &= Animation(size=(500, 500))
        animation += Animation(size=(100, 50))

        # apply the animation on the button, passed in the "instance" argument
        animation.start(instance)

    def build(self):
        # create a button, and  attach animate() method as a on_press handler
        button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), text='plop', on_press=self.animate)
        return button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Вот простой пример. Не работающий. Запускаю, как обычный python скрипт.

Comment: Недостаточно деталей в вопросе. Приведите пример кода, покажите, как его запускаете, укажите версию Python и окружение.

Comment: Python 2.7. Ставил Kivy через менеджер пакетов Synaptic. Не думаю, что какая-то библиотека не установилась.

Comment: ваш код рабочий, переустановите киви по инструкции с родного сайта, попробуйте что то поменять в коде, может после пару запусков киви расклинит, у меня в PyCharm c 3-го раза заработал, а то без ошибок только запускал как тест

Comment: Да все нормально уже работает, но с этим Kivy проблемы всегда! В основном из-за видео драйверов.